# Timeout exception in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-database

**Error: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds**

I get this error but didn't find any specific line in project.Below is my logcat output:

```
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeClose(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.dispose(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.finalize(SQLiteConnection.java:178)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collector tries to clear your `SQLiteConnection` instance, which you have forgot to close yourself. Take care of `close()`ing db instance.

Comment: Show where and how you have used SQLite database.

Comment: I am using database in whole project many times. Am i need to close SQLIteConnection in every function in which I do a query?

Comment: That would be useless overhead. Say you opened a connection in an activity, you should take care to close that connection when activity is being finished, otherwise that connection would stay opened and no one would use it - memory leak.

Comment: I am using in activity like this `SQLitehalper sqlitehelper = new SQLitehalper(Mainactivity.this);
sqlitehelper.deleteData(Integer.parseInt(id));`

Comment: You should call [`sclitehelper.close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close()) when you are done with it.

Comment: can i close it in onDestroy() in activity? and what if i use fragment?

Comment: Yes you can. You can reuse the same instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` throughout activity, no need to create a new one in each fragment.

Comment: I am using to retrieve arraylist from databse like this `ArrayList = sqlitehelper.selectAllData();`  so can I close `ArrayList = sqlitehelper.selectAllData();
 sqlitehelper.close();` like this ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: I get error 1 in 1000 times . so probably it's  happened due to forgetting close connection.

Comment: and one last thing how to use **instance of SQLiteOpenHelper throughout activity** . I am using navigation drawer in mainactivity .

Comment: Use dependency injection tool like [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/) which will provide you singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Then inject component who need to deal with database.

Comment: It's looking difficult for newbie like me . But Thanks. Tell me if another link that provide easy document for understanding . Thanks for help.

Comment: Have a application wide singleton instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Look for "singleton pattern".